# Monotouch - Installing Xcode to a different than default folder problem

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

We set up a new Mac, installed xcode3 to the **/Developer/xcode3** folder instead of the default **/Developer**

When we run Monotouch is says that "*The Apple iPhone SDK is not installed*"

How do I tell Monotouch to look in **/developer/xcode3** instead of the default?

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem when I first started and used this for a solution.

http://blog.ehuna.org/2011/01/monodevelop_how_to_fix_the_bui.html

Although there may be some side effects if you decide to move to xcode4 (not sure if monotouch supports this yet)

As far as I know there isn't a way to change the SDK path in monotouch.